# c++ templated map, common interface for different type of parameters

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, stdmap

I have parameter class, which contains different types of parameters.

```
  std::map<std::string, std::string >        _params_string;
  std::map<std::string, int    >             _params_int;
  std::map<std::string, double      >        _params_double;
  std::map<std::string, bool        >        _params_bool;
```

I would like to have one method, where user can set parameters as:

```
  template<class type>
  inline void set(const std::string &key, const type &value)
  {
      _params[key] = value;
  }
```

but, since I have different storage for different types of params, it is becoming mess.

Does anybody have any suggestion for common interface/ storage for different type of parameters?

Comment: Unless you expect to support "parameters" of the same name for multiple types, that is have an "a" `std::string` parameter and an "a" `bool` parameter, you need to redesign and reengineer your class. It's not designed right. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why not to use `std::map<std::string, boost::variant<std::string, int, double, bool>>` ?

Comment: Just write 4 overloads for the set function.

Comment: Eissa N.'s suggestion is the simplest (and perhaps best) solution.  But if you have many more than four types, or are dealing with many more functions that need overloading, I give a possible solution in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a discriminated union like Boost.Variant to reduce all your maps to just:

```
using Parameter = boost::variant<int, double, bool, std::string>;
std::map<std::string, Parameter> _params;
```

Now that you only have one map, you (obviously) only need one `set()`:

```
template <class T>
void set(std::string const& key, T const& value) {
    _params[key] = value;
}
```

Each parameter will know what type it is holding. This additionally resolves an issue with having the same key exist in multiple maps - since that makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several ways to do this.  But the simplest one I can think of requires C++ 14 support.

### Tuples, C++ 14

```
template <typename T>
using stringmap = std::map<std::string, T>;

std::tuple<stringmap<std::string>, stringmap<std::int>, stringmap<std::double>, stringmap<std::bool>> _params;

template <typename T>
explicit void set(const std::string & key, const T & value) {
    std::get<stringmap<T>>(_params)[key] = value;
}
```

You can do a similar dance with `get`, and you can always get a reference to the map of choice using `std::get<stringmap<T>>(_params)` for a particular type.

### Tuples, C++ 11

You can do this in an identical manner, as long as you are willing to write a get routine on tuples that can be indexed by type.  Here is one I wrote called `tget`.

```
template <std::size_t Pos, std::size_t Count, typename T, typename... Rest>
struct _tget_tuple_helper {
    static constexpr auto pos = Pos;
    static constexpr auto count = Count;
};

template <std::size_t Pos, std::size_t Count, typename T, typename S, typename... Rest>
struct _tget_tuple_helper<Pos, Count, T, S, Rest...> {
    static constexpr auto match = std::is_same<T, typename std::decay<S>::type>::value;
    using parent = _tget_tuple_helper<Pos + 1, match ? Count + 1 : Count, T, Rest...>;
    static constexpr auto pos = match ? Pos : parent::pos;
    static constexpr auto count = parent::count;
};

template <typename T, typename... Types>
using tget_tuple_helper = _tget_tuple_helper<0, 0, typename std::decay<T>::type, Types...>;

template <typename T, typename... Types>
constexpr
typename std::enable_if<tget_tuple_helper<T, Types...>::count == 1, T &>::type
tget(std::tuple<Types...> & t) {
    return std::get<tget_tuple_helper<T, Types...>::pos>(t);
}
template <typename T, typename... Types>
constexpr
typename std::enable_if<tget_tuple_helper<T, Types...>::count == 1, const T &>::type
tget(const std::tuple<Types...> & t) {
    return std::get<tget_tuple_helper<T, Types...>::pos>(t);
}
```

With this, you can replace `std::get` with `tget` in the C++ 14 example.  Everything else should work just the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use it with any type like this `std::map<std::string,std::experimental::any>`

Link: [c++ 17 any type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)